# Blender Python scripting: rendering and keyframes

Tags: python, rendering, animation, scripting, keyframes

I am new to Blender and I’m having a bit of a tough time understanding its key concepts. I am using Blender 2.82 and working with Python scripting. My project consists of using Python to do the following:

1. Move object slightly.
2. Take picture with camera 1, camera 2, camera 3, and camera 4.
3. Repeat.

I had a script that did that. However, I wanted to save the position of my object (a sphere) every time I changed it during the loop in an animation, so I could later see what I did. When trying to insert keyframes for animation in my loop, it seems as if my sphere didn’t move. Below is my code. When I remove the lines that include `frame_set` and `keyframe_insert`, my sphere moves as I can see from my rendered images. I think I am confusing some kind of concept… Any help would be appreciated. The goal of this is to produce the images I would obtain from four cameras placed around an object, that is moving, so as to simulate a mocap system.

```
import bpy, bgl, blf,sys
import numpy as np
from bpy import data, ops, props, types, context

cameraNames=''

# Loop all command line arguments and try to find "cameras=east" or similar
for arg in sys.argv:
    words=arg.split('=')
    if ( words[0] == 'cameras'):
     cameraNames = words[1]

sceneKey = bpy.data.scenes.keys()[0]

# Loop all objects and try to find Cameras
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].render.image_settings.file_format = 'JPEG'
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].cycles.max_bounces=12
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].render.tile_x=8
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].render.tile_y=8
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].cycles.samples = 16
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].cycles.caustics_reflective = False
bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].cycles.caustics_refractive = False

bpy.data.objects['Sphere'].location=[1,1,1] 
frame_num=0
for i in range(0,2): #nframes
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        # Find cameras that match cameraNames
        if ( obj.type =='CAMERA') and ( cameraNames == '' or obj.name.find(cameraNames) != -1) :

          # Set Scenes camera and output filename
            bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].camera = obj
            bpy.data.scenes[sceneKey].render.filepath = '//'+obj.name+"_"+str(i) 

          # Render Scene and store the scene
            bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )

    bpy.data.objects['Sphere'].keyframe_insert(data_path="location",index=-1)
    frame_num+=1
    bpy.data.objects['Sphere'].location=[2,2,1]
```

Comment: The problem shows up when I do "keyframe_insert", commenting that line solves the issue. But it doesn't build up my animation so that I can play it later, which is something I wish to do. Why does this line make my sphere not move in my rendered pictures? How can I solve it?

Comment: Sorry @RayMairlot, it's the first time I post on a forum. I will try to edit the post. Thank you for the suggestion!